# Django Queryset in forms

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-queryset

How can i make a queryset in this modelform. This is my code.

```
Class Sample(forms.ModelForm):  
    class Meta:  
        model = Customer  
        fields = ('name','address',)  
        widgets = {  
            'name' : Select(attrs={'class':'span2'}),  
            'address' : TextInput(attrs={'class':'span4'}),  
             }  
        queryset = {'name': User.objects.filter(type_id=1)}
```

Is this the right way in using queryset? Pls help me.

Thank You.

Answer (score 2):

```
Class Sample(forms.ModelForm):  
    class Meta:  
        model = Customer  
        fields = ('name','address',)  
        widgets = {  
            'name' : Select(attrs={'class':'span2'}),  
            'address' : TextInput(attrs={'class':'span4'}),  
             }  

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Sample, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['name'].queryset = User.objects.filter(type_id=1)
```