# Django Queryset in ModelForm using a 'pk'

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-forms

I'm trying to follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15985157/django-queryset-in-forms) SO Q&A which is exactly what I want to do but with a `pk` instead of a fixed key.  My files...

views.py

```
class JuryCreate(CreateView):
    model = Jury
    form_class = JuryCreateForm

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.customer_id = self.kwargs['pk']
        form.instance.court_year_id = self.kwargs['yr']
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

forms.py

```
class JuryCreateForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Jury
        fields = [
            'parent_jury',
            #Other Fields
            ]

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['parent_jury'].queryset = Jury.objects.filter(
            customer_id = self.kwargs['pk']).filter(
            court_year_id = self.kwargs['yr'])
```

If i go directly from the `view` to the template I'm able to access the queryset (it provides a queryset object).  But if I go through the ModelForm it throws an `AttributeError: 'JuryCreateForm' object has no attribute 'kwargs'`.  Basically, I bleive that the request isn't passed to the ModelForm so it can't access the kwargs.  How do I get the primary keys into the ModelForm to populate the fields?

I've also tried variations of `get_form_kwargs` method that I think is the appropriate mechanism to pass these to the ModelForm - I just can't get it to implement correctly (or get it in the right class object).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to override view's `get_form_kwargs` method like this:

```
class JuryCreate(CreateView):
    model = Jury
    form_class = JuryCreateForm

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.customer_id = self.kwargs['pk']
        form.instance.court_year_id = self.kwargs['yr']
        return super().form_valid(form)

    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        kwargs = super().get_form_kwargs()
        kwargs['pk'] = self.kwargs['pk']
        kwargs['yr'] = self.kwargs['yr']
        return kwargs
```

In form init use `kwargs['pk']` or `kwargs.pop('pk')` to access `pk` value:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    pk = kwargs.pop('pk')
    yr = kwargs.pop('yr') 
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['parent_jury'].queryset = Jury.objects.filter(
        customer_id = pk).filter(
        court_year_id = yr)
```

Comment: This throws:  `ModelFormMetaclass object argument after ** must be a mapping, not NoneType` - but i feel this is on the right track - I just can't get it to pass correct.

Comment: @BillArmstrong sorry, I missed `return kwargs` in `get_form_kwargs`. Check updated answer.

Comment: Boom... yes - the thing I was missing was the `.pop()` and then removal of `.self` in the ModelForm class.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

## And getting the Template to work

As a final follow-on to `@neverwalkaloner`'s correct answer - - once the Queryset is initialized in the ModelForm, it is displayed in the template as follows (or at least the quickest way I found):

jury-update.html

```
<select>
    {% for item in form.parent_jury.field.queryset %}
        <option value="{{item}}">{{ item }}</option>
    {% endfor %}
</select>
```